# RMI on Raspberry Pi not working Connection refused to host : 127.0.0.1

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, rmi

I am trying to communicate between server (on Pi) and client (on another PI) using java RMI. The Client is able to call the remote methods of the Server but when Server tries to access the remote method of client I get the error of `Connection refused to Host 127.0.0.1.` To solve this I set the `System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", ServerIP;` but then get the error of `Connection refused to Host 10.10.*.*.`

The MasterInterface looks like

```
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;


public interface MasterInterface extends Remote{
    public void sayHello(String s) throws RemoteException;

}
```

The Master.java file looks like

```
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;


public class Master extends UnicastRemoteObject implements MasterInterface{

    protected Master() throws RemoteException {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
        System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", "192.168.4.*");
            Master master = new Master();
            Registry reg = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(9898);
            reg.rebind("Master", master);
            System.out.println("Master is on.123123132.test.");


        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void sayHello(String s) throws RemoteException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Hiiiiiii ->>>>>"+s);
        try{

        Registry regi2 = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("192.168.*.*", 9898);
        System.out.println("asdasdasd1!!");
        SlaveInterface bsObj1 = (SlaveInterface) regi2.lookup("Slave");
        bsObj1.saybye("madhav");
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

The SlaveInterface looks like

```
    import java.rmi.Remote;
    import java.rmi.RemoteException;


    public interface SlaveInterface extends Remote{

        public void saybye(String s) throws RemoteException;

    }
```

The Slave.java files look like

```
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;


public class Slave extends UnicastRemoteObject implements SlaveInterface {
    private final static String master_IP = "192.168.4.*";
    protected Slave() throws RemoteException {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
            System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", "192.168.*.*");
            Slave s = new Slave();
        Registry regclient = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(2525);
        System.out.println("slave obj bound!!");
        regclient.rebind("Slave", s);
        System.out.println("Slave is on..");

        Registry regi = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(master_IP, 9898);
        System.out.println("slave obj bound1111!!");
        MasterInterface bsObj = (MasterInterface) regi.lookup("Master");
        System.out.println("slave obj bound2222!!");
        bsObj.sayHello("hi karan");
        System.out.println("done................");
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("not working!!!!!!!!!!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void saybye(String s) throws RemoteException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("bye "+s);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `java.rmi.server.hostname` to the extermal IP address of the server in the server JVM before exporting any remote objects. See the [RMI FAQ item A.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/faq.html#domain).

Comment: just to make it clear whenever I want my client to invoke server method I should set java.rmi.server.hostname to server Ip in the client and similarly whenever I want  my server to invoke client method I should set to client IP in the server ?

Comment: You should do exactly what I said: set it 'in the server JVM before exporting any remote objects'. Neither of the alternatives you mention bears any resemblance to that.

Comment: I did that changes as shown in the code but still get the error of connection refused to 192.168.*.* when master invoke client methods in the sayHello method. I get to the point where it prints "asdasdasd1!!" and then crash

Comment: So you set an invalid IP address. What did you expect? `192.168.*.*` isn't an IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem a few year ago, because of the name resolution (by default the hostname will resolve to 127.0.0.1 - the IP address of the loopback interface).

If you do not have a DNS server, try this:

Assign to both Pi a different hostname (set it in `/etc/hostname`) or use the `hostname` command.

If you use for example "master" and "client" as hostnames, and 10.10.10.13 and 10.10.10.14 are their IP addresses, add the following information to the file `/etc/hosts`, in both Pi:

```
10.10.10.13 master
10.10.10.14 client
```

Comment: here the tricky part that comes in. I do not have access to the etc/host. My Master only has the IP of the client. I send the java files to client using SFTP creating a ssh connection(Jcraft) to it and then run a script to run it. So I can't modify the client host file.

Comment: try half of the solution, i.e., the master part. You have root access to the master, right? (add both IP addresses to the master hosts file)

Comment: The client entry isn't required for any purpose of RMI.